# Toggle entire jQuery jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

Is it possible to open and close the entire tree through a button?

I know that in order to open all the nodes and subnodes of the tree, I have to call the open_all function like : `$("#tree").jstree('open_all');`

And in order to toggle a node : `$("#tree").jstree("toggle_node","#1");` where #1 is the id of the first child.

But the toggle function does not expand all the subnodes of the node. Nor does it open a half-opened tree. I can call open_all and close_all on button click, but how do I find which method to call, as in figure out if the tree has to be opened or closed?

Answer (score 11):

Pass -1 for the entire tree:

```
$("#tree").jstree("open_all", -1);
```

To close all you can use the close_all function:

```
$("#tree").jstree("close_all", -1);
```

You can also use `save_opened` to remember which nodes are opened and then reopen them later with the `reopen` function.

Look at the [documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core).

Comment: Same questions as above. Which function do I use to know that all nodes are expanded in the tree and that on another button click, I need to close them all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#treepanel").jstree("open_node", $('li[id="' + nodeId + '"]'), function() {
   alert("node is added")
});
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

```
function toggle(){
    var open=true;
    $(".jstree").jstree().on('loaded.jstree', function () {
         if(open){
              $(".jstree").jstree('close_all');
         }else{
              $(".jstree").jstree('close_all');
         }    
         open=!open; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used open_node and passed the identifier for the root node to expand all children. It works fine for me.

```
$('#tree').jstree('open_node', '#root');
```

Comment: But how do I figure out that the tree is half open or half closed or even fully closed/open?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img onclick="jstreeToggleState()" src='toggle-image.jpg'></img>

  <script>
   var isTreeOpen = false;

   function jstreeToggleState() {

        if(isTreeOpen){
              $(".jstree").jstree('close_all');
         }else{
              $(".jstree").jstree('open_all');
         }    
         isTreeOpen =! isTreeOpen; 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

piggybacking on @بهنام محمدی answer
This will toggle open and closed on a button as follows:

```
<button class="product-expand" onclick="toggle()">Toggle Open/Close</button>

var open = false;
function toggle(){
   if(open){
    $("#prodtree").jstree('close_all');
    open = false;
   }
   else{
    $("#prodtree").jstree('open_all');
    open = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.jstree({
    "core": {
        'data': jsondata,
        **expand_selected_onload: true**
    },
    "plugins": ["checkbox"]
})
```

Comment: expand_selected_onload: true to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.